# Mean position of random walk with only $+1$ jumps, with probability $\frac{c^x}{t-x+1}$ at time $t$ and site $x$

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Consider the following random walk in one dimension, starting from $r(0)=0$.
$$
r(i+1) = r(i) + \xi,
$$
where $\xi(i, r(i))$ is an increment with distribution $P(\xi=1) = \frac{c^{r(i)}}{i-r(i)+1}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\xi=0) = 1 -\mathbb{P}(\xi=1)$, with $c<1$ constant.

The question is: does the expectation $\mathbb{E}[r(i)]$ goes to infinity as $i$ goes to infinity or does it converge to a constant? For instance could it be of order $O( \log(i) )$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process $(r_c(t))$ based on $P(\xi(t,n)=1)=c^n$ jumps from $n$ to $n+1$ after a geometric time with mean $1/c^n$ hence $(r_c(t))$ hits $n$ after $\Theta(1/c^n)$ steps. Since $E(r_c(t))=\Theta(\log t)$ and $r_c(t)\geqslant r(t)$, $E(r(t))=O(\log t)$.

On the other hand, $r(t)\to+\infty$ almost surely. Otherwise, $r(t)$ would stay at some level $n$ forever after some time $t\geqslant n$, which happens with probability
$$
\prod_{s=t}^\infty\left(1-\frac{c^n}{s-n+1}\right)=0.
$$

Comment: In your answer it is true that, given $i$, $a^{Q} \leq \frac{c^Q}{i - Q + 1}$ for $Q$ large enough which depends on $i$. But in the process $Q$ depends on $i$ in a nontrivial way. So it is true that $r_a(i) \leq r(i) + O(1)$?  P.S. I edited the question using only one index, $i$, to make things more clear. Was this the origin of the misunderstanding?

Comment: In the first part of the answer, how does it follow that $E[r(i)]=O(log[i])$ if $r_c(i) \geq r(i)$?

Thanks for the second answer. I agree that the probability for the process to stay always at the same level is 0. But the expected time of the next jump should be infinite. So does $E[r(i)]$ really grow to infinite?

Comment: Given the current level $n$ and current time $i^*$, the expected time of the next jump is, $\sum_{i=i*}^{\infty} \, \, (i-i^*) [\prod_{s=i^*+1}^i (1 - \frac{c^n}{s-n+1})]\frac{c^n}{i-n+1}$, which is infinite.

Then, the process goes to infinite a.s. but the expected time of the next jump is infinite. What can we say about $E[r(i)]$ then?

Comment: Hint: Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem.